# MySql dump custom path

Tags: path, mysql

I'm trying to import a database (Gene Ontology database ) in order to have my own local copy. The instruction that I'm using to import it are:

```
echo "create database mygo" | mysql
cat *.sql | mysql mygo
mysqlimport -L mygo *.txt
```

The dataset is huge (more than 30 GB) and I'd like to specify the path where to store it and not use the default mysql location. Is it possible? If yes, which commands should I use?

Comment: Location of data files is a per-server setting (run `SELECT @@datadir` to check current value). You can't change it for current session or anything like that.

Comment: What if I change it permanently? Is it possible?

Comment: edit my.cnf http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000